# Android: Decoding an encoded LatLngList with PolyUtil.decode causes StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, list, exception, encoding, decoding

I've an Android application which loads routes from the database. These routes are encoded lists of LatLng objects. I am using the PolyUtil library for encoding and decoding of the list of LatLng objects:

`final String encodedLatLngList = PolyUtil.encode(recordedLatLngList);`

and

`List<LatLng> decodedLatLngList = PolyUtil.decode(encodedLatLngList[i]);`

Usually everything works perfectly with the encoding and decoding of these lists and strings, however, there are routes in the database uploaded from a different device which all throw expections:

`routeID 55 caused java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=879; index=879
 routeID 65 caused java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=171; index=171
 routeID 66 caused java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=215; index=215`

There are longer routes saved in the database where no problem occurs also are the encoded lists free of null objects as every retrieved Location and LatLng object are checked against null before operations and insertions. Any thoughts what could cause the problem with these?

This is the whole code of this section:

```
JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, server_url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        // response
                        int count = 0;
                        int databaseEntries = response.length();

                        int[] routeID = new int[databaseEntries];
                        String[] encodedLatLngList = new String[databaseEntries];
                        int[] routeLength = new int[databaseEntries];
                        int[] routeColor = new int[databaseEntries];
                        String[] routeKeywords = new String[databaseEntries];
                        markerMap = new HashMap();

                        while (count < response.length()) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(count);

                                routeID[count] = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getString("route_id")); //ID

                                encodedLatLngList[count] = jsonObject.getString("route_LatLngData");//Array

                                routeLength[count] = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getString("route_length")); //length

                                routeColor[count] = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getString("route_color")); //Color

                                routeKeywords[count] = jsonObject.getString("route_keywords");

                                count++;

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();

                                Toast.makeText(context, "Something went wrong while trying to add existing routes to map", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }

                        for (int i = 0; i < databaseEntries - 1; i++) {

                            try {

                                List<LatLng> decodedLatLngList = PolyUtil.decode(encodedLatLngList[i]);

                            //  LatLng[] latLngArray = decodedLatLngList.toArray(new LatLng[0]);

                            //  Route route = new Route(context, routeID[i], latLngArray, routeLength[i], routeColor[i], routeKeywords[i]);

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.d("filteredRoutes", "routeID: " + routeID[i] + " caused: " + e.toString());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // error response
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Internet connection failed. loadAllAvailableRoutes file not found.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
        );
        //Adds post request to request queue using MySingleton class.
        MySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);
    }
```

The stack trace looks as follows:

```
04-22 02:55:14.403 2838-2838/com.universityofportsmouth.kaanapaydin.runarace W/System.err: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=80; index=80
04-22 02:55:14.403 2838-2838/com.universityofportsmouth.kaanapaydin.runarace W/System.err:     at java.lang.String.charAt(Native Method)
04-22 02:55:14.403 2838-2838/com.universityofportsmouth.kaanapaydin.runarace W/System.err:     at com.google.maps.android.PolyUtil.decode(PolyUtil.java:464)
04-22 02:55:14.403 2838-2838/com.universityofportsmouth.kaanapaydin.runarace W/System.err:     at com.universityofportsmouth.kaanapaydin.runarace.Route$1.onResponse(Route.java:157)
04-22 02:55:14.403 2838-2838/com.universityofportsmouth.kaanapaydin.runarace W/System.err:     at com.universityofportsmouth.kaanapaydin.runarace.Route$1.onResponse(Route.java:115)
04-22 02:55:14.403 2838-2838/com.universityofportsmouth.kaanapaydin.runarace W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:83)
04-22 02:55:14.403 2838-2838/com.universityofportsmouth.kaanapaydin.runarace W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:106)
04-22 02:55:14.403 2838-2838/com.universityofportsmouth.kaanapaydin.runarace W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:743)
04-22 02:55:14.403 2838-2838/com.universityofportsmouth.kaanapaydin.runarace W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-22 02:55:14.403 2838-2838/com.universityofportsmouth.kaanapaydin.runarace W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
04-22 02:55:14.403 2838-2838/com.universityofportsmouth.kaanapaydin.runarace W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5621)
04-22 02:55:14.403 2838-2838/com.universityofportsmouth.kaanapaydin.runarace W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-22 02:55:14.403 2838-2838/com.universityofportsmouth.kaanapaydin.runarace W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
04-22 02:55:14.403 2838-2838/com.universityofportsmouth.kaanapaydin.runarace W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:684)
04-22 02:55:14.403 2838-2838/com.universityofportsmouth.kaanapaydin.runarace D/filteredRoutes: routeID: 69 caused: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=80; index=80
```

The PolyUtil decode method with the failed line:

```
   public static List<LatLng> decode(String encodedPath) {
        int len = encodedPath.length();
        List<LatLng> path = new ArrayList();
        int index = 0;
        int lat = 0;
        int lng = 0;

        /*
         * Modifying this line to len-1 caused proper functionality.
         * Maybe one location is now missing on the other routes
         * but that is still better than having no routes uloaded by other users.
         */
        while(index < len) {  //  
            int result = 1;
            int shift = 0;

            int b;
            do {
                b = encodedPath.charAt(index++) - 63 - 1;
                result += b << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while(b >= 31);

            lat += (result & 1) != 0?~(result >> 1):result >> 1;
            result = 1;
            shift = 0;

            do {
                b = encodedPath.charAt(index++) - 63 - 1; //this line enters a too high index
                result += b << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while(b >= 31);

            lng += (result & 1) != 0?~(result >> 1):result >> 1;
            path.add(new LatLng((double)lat * 1.0E-5D, (double)lng * 1.0E-5D));
        }

        return path;
    }
```

The string that causes the out of index exception:

```
tp|_Fy~ui`@??NHKR@RJPHJHP@HHPRDJEFAC@@?@??@@A@?B@?NBXDLJHHJLXBJDJDFFFFHNXNATEH??
```

Comment: Do you have the full stack trace? It would be useful to see the line number within PolyUtil where the crash occurs.

Comment: @stkent I've added the stack trace. Hope it helps

Comment: `while(index < len)`. That is ok. `index` should be smaller than `len'.

Comment: `do {
                b = encodedPath.charAt(index++) - 63 - 1;`. Here you are blindly incrementing `index` whithout checking if it is still smaller than `len`. Add that check here too.

Comment: @greenapps That code is actually in Google's map services code, not on Kaan's own code. The real question here is if there is a bug on Google's end or no